# UIActivityIndicatorView is not working (getting Facebook permissions affecting UIActivityIndicatorView)

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a tabbarcontroller with three tabs/viewcontrollers.

When I first start my app, with my ActivityIndicator set to be visible and animated - courtesy of interface builder - it works fine.

However when I click a button an internet window opens to Facebook in order to get the user's permission.

Once the Facebook part is taken care it returns to my app but the ActivityIndicator is not longer animated - it is still visible though, just frozen.

If I switch to another tab/viewcontroller and then come back to the tab/viewcontroller with the ActivityIndicator everything works fine.

Is there a way to refresh my ViewController so that I don't have to programmatically make the ViewController switch back and forth? Or any other suggestions?

/* I searched the forums and I saw a similar question. It appeared that there was a broken connection. Therefore I'll include the code where I add the ViewController (i.e., "controller" to my tabbarcontroller). */

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    controller = [[DemoAppViewController alloc] init];
    controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 460);
    controller.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"movieAppBackground.jpg"]];
    MyTabBarViewController *vc2 = [[MyTabBarViewController alloc] init];
    SecondViewController *vc3 = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];

    controller.title = @"Intro Screen";
    vc2.title = @"Explore";
    vc3.title = @"Send a Pic";

    UITabBarController *tbc = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    tbc.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:controller, vc2, vc3, nil];
    self.theTBC=tbc;

    [controller release];
    [vc2 release];
    [vc3 release];
    [tbc release];

    [self.window addSubview:tbc.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

  return YES;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

whereever u have used NIB file to show with viewcontrollers u have to create them with initwithname

Example

```
     SecondViewController *r=[[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
```

like this change whereever u have used nib file to create instance,

i meaned for all custom viewcontrollers u have created with NIB file

Comment: Thanks @Vijay - I'll be sure to init all three of my viewcontrollers with the initWithNibName :-) However, I did try that for the ViewController that was giving me problems and it still didn't help.

Comment: Not sure if this is the right way to check for an error but I did    `NSLog(@"%@",aiView.hidden=NO);` and it returned `(NULL)` which is the same as when I switch tabs first (i.e., when it animates properly)